# Differentiating random and ordered sequential mechanisms in enzyme kinetics

Tags: biochemistry, kinetics, enzymes

Can random and ordered sequential mechanisms be descern by Lineweaver-Burk plot? Why or why not? Because for orederd sequential mechanism I got different LB plot depending on which substrate is held constant (when A, which binds first to the enzyme, is held constant lines for different concentrations of A in Lineweaver-Burk plot have same intercept 1/Vmax). And how are they differed based on product inhibition studies?